# how to use a slash in route parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, url, express

I have a GET REST service which needs to accept parameters with a /

URL = "/term/:term/amount/:amount"
where :term can be a string like "para/5MG".

is there a way to do this in express? as my api gets used, I prefer not to rewrite it with queryparams.

Comment: encode the slash http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, express tries to split at `/` so you'll have to do splitting by hand. Here is one example of doing so:

```
app.get('/term/\\S+/amount/:amount', function (req, res, next){
  var match;
  if(match = req.path.match(/^\/term\/(.*?)\/amount\/(.*)$/)){
    var term = match[1];
    var amount = req.params.amount;
    // or do whatever you like

    res.json({term: term, amount: amount})
  }else{
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
})
```

You'll loose a lot of expresse's built in magic with this method. It probably would be better to URI-encode the parameter in the first place. (like this: `term/para%2F5MG/amount/3`)

Comment: Thank you, URI encoding seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/term/:term/amount/:amount',  function(req, res) {
    // your code here
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, have you tried `curl <hostname>/term/para/5MG/amount/5` ?

Comment: You need to URI encode the forward slash, try this: `curl <hostname>/term/para%2F5MG/amount/5`

Comment: Why isn't that part of your answer then?

Comment: I didn't notice the nuance of forward slash being part of the parameter when originally reading the question. I thought the OP just didn't know how to create an express route with named parameters.